# onClick event calls prototype method, have problem with 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsx, dom-events

I'm using react in my project.
When `button.onClick`, I want to call prototype method (`this.changeFont`) that changes fontstyle of `&('body')`. The name of fontstyle is in prototype property named 'valuename'

but when I click button, error says:

> "cannot read valuename of undefined".

Is it because when I click the button, 'this' becomes 'event', not an object?

I tried 
 `var _this = this;` 
 and change `to _this.valuename`,
 but error says it cannot read undefined _this.

```
function FontClass(name, valuename) {
    this.name = name;
    this.valuename = valuename;
}


FontClass.prototype.changeFont =function(){
    $('body').css("font-family", this.valuename);

}



var fira = new FontClass("Fria", "Fira Code");



const Nav = ({style}) => {


    return( 

        <animated.div className="nav-wrapper" style={style}>
            <div>
            new array=[<button onClick={fira.changeFont}>{fira.name}</button>]
            </div>

            <div>

            </div>

        </animated.div>     

    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a javascript class instead of a function and use an arrow function to bind `this`.

```
class FontClass {
  constructor(name, valuename) {
    this.name = name;
    this.valuename = valuename;
  }

  changeFont = () => {
    $("body").css("font-family", this.valuename);
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Or the other way is to pass the value during function call

```
function FontClass(name, valuename) {
    this.name = name;
    this.valuename = valuename;
}


FontClass.prototype.changeFont = function(valuename){
    $('body').css("font-family", valuename);
}



var fira = new FontClass("Fria", "Fira Code");



const Nav = ({style}) => {
    return( 
        <animated.div className="nav-wrapper" style={style}>
            <div>
            new array=[<button onClick={() => fira.changeFont(fira.valuename)}>{fira.name}</button>]
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </animated.div>     
    );
}
```